# Why doesn't overflow scroll work on the html tag in mobile webkit?

Tags: html, css, webkit, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

Here is a simple html document where there is a div that overflows the document to the right because of the horizontal translation.  But because overflow is set to hidden on the html tag, I would expect there to be no scrollbar.  This is the case in google chrome, but when I load this document in mobile webkit, or mobile safari, I am able to scroll.  Is this a bug?  How can I get around this?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      background: lightgray;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .test {
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(90%, 0, 0);
      height: 100px;
      background: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To reproduce the issue, you can open this link in mobile safari or mobile webkit.  You can also reproduce it by opening chrome dev tools and enabling device metrics overrides to simulate a mobile device.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78736800/overflowscrollbug.html

Answer (score 0):

You should also hide the overflow of the `body`.  I ran a quick test and this did the trick in mobile Safari:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    background: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.test {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(90%, 0, 0);
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
</style>
```